# TreeViewer with a Composite as content

Tags: java, treeview, swt, jface

I want to build a Tree with a custom bunch of widgets as content. So not only a simple label, but something more complex arranged in a Composite. Is this possible in current SWT/JFace (3.7)? If yes, how do I do that? TreeViewer does only allow me to set a LabelProvider, that has only a `getImage()` and `getText()` method. Or am I limited to just that, an image and a simple label without any markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't *quite* that limited -- there is [`CellLabelProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/class-use/CellLabelProvider.html), which lets you do things like draw graphics inside cell -- but as far as I know, there is no way to put arbitrary controls inside table or tree cells. This is unsurprising, because SWT generally can only do something if it is supported on all OSes and window systems where SWT is available.

Comment: Ok, a I see it's impossible in SWT to have a richer tree. Thanks!